# Using MS Word, how do I add a new section within all existing sections of a document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a very large word document that is structured using the various headings so that I can view the structured document in the Navigation Pane.

Lets say I have a hundred sections that look (structurally) like this:

```
 - Section Title
   -- Summary
   --- Items
```

Now let's say that for each of those hundred sections, I need to add a new one:

```
 - Section Title
   -- Summary
   --- MY NEW SECTION
   ---- MY NEW SUBSECTION
   --- Items
```

Is there a quick way to add this new section to each of those hundred others all at once?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Find/Replace and go for the format of the Summary line ["Header2" ?], and then replace it with Summary+NEWsection+NEWSubsection.

Prepare the new structure in one example, copy it, and then use Find/Replace, put the copied stuff in the Replace Box, (using \1 for the summary if needed), and the format of Summary in the Find Box. make sure to active the Formatting searching.

I did not try this specific example, but have done similar replaces in the past, and they went fine. It is not a trivial activity, but if you fiddle a bit, you should get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is to go to the Chapter view, and select the two you want to copy around (NEWsection+NEWSubsection), and then hold down CTRL (for 'Copy') and drag them to each place where you want them.

That's a hundred drags/drops,yes, but it is simple and straightforward, and takes a second per action.